# How to get click event of input text field in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Can you please tell me how to get the click event of an input text field in jQuery? I have one input text field I need click event of that showing alert.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="text-12" class="name_label_field">Name<span class="custom-label">*</span> :</label><span class="mandatory_label fright custom-label">*<span class="test_1">Maximum Limit 260</span></span>
    <input name="text-12" id="text-12" value="" type="text" class="documentName_h name_input_box" autocorrect="off" maxlength="240" onkeypress="validateNote(event)">
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p9TC4/

Answer (score 2):

```
 $('#text-12').click(function(e) {
     alert('clicked');
 });
```

in general, for all text inputs, use `input[type="text"]` instead of `#text-12` selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below

```
$('#text-12').click(function(){ alert("hello")});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
$('#text-12').on('click',function(){alert("alert-title")});
```